# Consolidate document libraries into one document library SharePoint 2010

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-enterprise

we have around 10 document libraries, is there a way to convert this 10 document libraries into folders and put them inside a document library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have additional metadata on those document libraries, the fastest way to do this I reckon is using Windows Explorer View to create folders in the target merged library, and to copy the files from the source libraries into the target.

Comment: Or use Content and Structure.

Comment: Hi James could you elaborate as to how to achieve this?..is it Out of Box?

Comment: It is indeed out of the box. IN the 'List' (or might be 'Library') tab of a document library, there should be an 'Open in Explorer' button. This lets you drag/drop files to/from the library.

Comment: I tried with the explorer view but i loose the originial modified by user metadata..is there a way to preserve that?